# New/blank line in itemize

Tags: spacing, itemize

I have an `itemize` area with several point inside it. I want to have the following result:

```
- one
- two

- three
```

Is there is an appropitate way to do so? As a workaround I used the following code to do what I want to have. But I hope there is a more nicer way :)

```
\item one
\item two
\item[~]  
\item three
```

Comment: "More nicer" would be `\newcommand{\blanklineitem}{\item[]}`. Creating a macro for this use is preferred, as you can adjust it in the future without modifying your code.

Answer (score 15):

You add vertical space in the same way you'd do outside `itemize`; it's not very clear *why* you'd do it in the first place.

The following code works also with `beamer`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item one
\item two

\bigskip

\item three
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

How about the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\frame{

\begin{itemize}
\item one
\item two \newline
\item three
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That don't works how I want. Maybe this is why have `\documentclass{beamer}`?

Comment: @florianm93: Instead of making the community guess what you're using and how, provide us with a complete, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) (click on the link!) that replicates your current problem. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It also works with Beamer, see my updated answer and next time please provide such information before people start helping you.

Comment: @florianm93: Providing a MWE would be great. However, if you just want to save some time typing the command `\item[~]` you could think about defining your own command like `\newcommand{\itemnewline}{\item[~]}`

Comment: @albert and Werner thanks for the advice about the MWE. The next time i remember this. It was my first question here. :)